# Merging two files based on a common column; add 0 for variants not present in file 2, and keep the original value in those which are present

Tags: text-processing, awk, join, merge

I would like to merge two files, which share some common data. File 1 includes more than file 2. I want to merge the files based on their shared column (3) following the order of file 1 and I want to add 0 to column 5 (AN1) when the variable is not present in file 2, and if present, add the original value of AN1 (either 0 or 1).

My files look like this: File 1

```
CHR BP  SNP CM  base
20  61098   rs6078030   -0.00024510777  1
20  61795   rs4814683   0   1
20  63231   rs6076506   0.0005026053    1
20  63244   rs6139074   0.00050714752   1
```

File 2

```
CHR BP  SNP CM  AN1
20 9836704 rs221007 0 1
20 9817032 rs221011 0 0
20 9764069 rs2206484 0 0
20 9639395 rs4816159 0 1
```

I want to match them based on column 3 (SNP). I want to keep all the other columns for now.

My desired output would look like this (0 when rsX is not present, or when the original value of AN1 was 0):

File 3

```
CHR BP  SNP CM  base AN1
20  61098   rs6078030   -0.00024510777  1   1
20  61795   rs4814683   0   1   0
20  63231   rs6076506   0.0005026053    1   0
20  63244   rs6139074   0.00050714752   1   1
```

I need to modify this code according to the new conditions:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ snp[$3]; next }
{ $6=($3 in snp)?(FNR==1?"AN1":"1"):"0" }1' file2 file1
```

Here I print 1 when rsX is present in file 1. I would like to print the original value of AN1 instead (0 or 1)

Comment: How large are the files, and how are the fields separated (space or tab)?

Comment: File 1 is like 100 MB and file 2 is around 10 MB. The fields are tab-separated. The above mentioned code works perfectly, but I don't know how to change that condition to what I want to do.

Comment: Are you sure that with your current approach File3 is also tab-separated? My guess is that it should now be space-separated ...

Comment: You are right, file 3 is space-separated, unlike files 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ snp[$3]=$NF; next }
{ $6=($3 in snp)?(FNR==1?"AN1":snp[$3]):"0" }1' file2 file1
```

Things in `awk`:

`NR`: The total number of input records seen so far.
`FNR`: The input record number in the current input file and will reset to 1 for the next input file.

So condition `NR==FNR` will always true for the first input file only and the following block `NR==FNR { ... }` will execute when it's true and we do save last column value `$NF` into an *awk* array `snp` with column `$3` as the keys.

`next` statement cause *awk* to skip executing the rest of the code and start over and if `NF==FNR` was still true it will repeat processing that block until all records/line of first input file read.

then in next block we add/update the value of column `$6` with below conditions:

- if column#3 in file1 was set in `snp` array from file2 then do:

  - if it's first line, set its value to *`AN1`*
  - if not first line, set its value to the value read from the *`snp[$3]`* array.
- else set to *`0`*.

the [*awk* idom `1`](/q/63891/72456) used to print the result after all.